# when using a returned element I get a different result vs. the full path, why?

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

I have the following code:

```
const [liveLayersFooter] = await page.$x("//div[@id='live-layers']/div[@class='footer']");
const [liveLayersEyeOn] = await liveLayersFooter.$x("//*[@id='eye-icon']");
const [liveLayersEyeOff] = await liveLayersFooter.$x("//div[@id='eye-off-icon']");

const [liveLayersEyeOnAll] = await page.$x("//div[@id='live-layers']/div[@class='footer']/div[@class='toggle-all ']/div[@class='eye-wrapper']/*[@id='eye-icon']");
const [liveLayersEyeOffAll] = await page.$x("//div[@id='live-layers']/div[@class='footer']/div[@class='toggle-all ']/div[@class='eye-wrapper off']/*[@id='eye-off-icon']");
```

According to the docs they should both return the same elementHandle relative to the element "footer". But only the bottom two with the full path spelled out returns the right elementHandles.

Id like to understand how I'm using the scope wrong for the var "liveLayersFooter".

Comment: Have you tried with `await liveLayersFooter.$x(".//*[@id='eye-icon']");` . `.` restrict the search to the parent element.

Comment: Interesting, I would think that using the elementHandle to call the .$x() search would already do that, but it doesn't... thanks!